# Gradle Javadoc GWT Error - cannot access Event in import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event

Tags: java, gradle, gwt, javadoc

I am trying to generate the javadoc of a GWT Java project using gradle. When I run the task **gradle build**, the compilation is successful. However, when I run the **gradle javadoc** task, it fails with the following error:

> C:\Users\jbraga.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.gwt\gwt-user\2.8.1\9a13fbee70848f1f1cddd3ae33ad180af3392d9e\gwt-user-2.8.1.jar(com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Widget.java):28: error: cannot access Event
>   import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
>                                    ^
>     bad source file: C:\Users\jbraga.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.gwt\gwt-user\2.8.1\9a13fbee70848f1f1cddd3ae33ad180af3392d9e\gwt-user-2.8.1.jar(com/google/gwt/user/client/Event.java)
>       file does not contain class com.google.gwt.user.client.Event
>       Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the sourcepath.
>   C:\Users\jbraga.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.gwt\gwt-user\2.8.1\9a13fbee70848f1f1cddd3ae33ad180af3392d9e\gwt-user-2.8.1.jar(com/google/gwt/layout/client/Layout.java):18: error: cannot find symbol
>   import static com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit.PX;
>   ^
>     symbol:   static PX
>     location: class
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':javadoc'.
>     Javadoc generation failed. Generated Javadoc options file (useful for troubleshooting): 'C:\Users\jbraga\odsoft-18-19-nmb-g302\odsoft\exercise1\component1\students\build\tmp\javadoc\javadoc.options'
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 4s

The GWT version I am using is 2.8.1 and the same occurs with 2.8.2. The gradle.properties file specifies the correct path to the SDK.

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known Gradle issue: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5630, fortunately with a known workaround:

```
javadoc {
  options.addStringOption("sourcepath", "")
}
```

Comment: I have to add
 javadoc {
options.addStringOption("sourcepath", "")
options.addBooleanOption("Xdoclint:none", true)
} Otherwise it was not able to recognise @param etc which we use in comments for java doc and throwing errors

Answer (score 0):

For me, a slight modification of Thomas Broyer suggested workaround has worked:

```
javadoc {
  options.addStringOption("sourcepath", "")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, fixed my answer